# Parsing Date in UpperCase to LocalDate

Tags: java, localdate

I'm trying to parse the String `FEBRUARY 2019` into a `LocalDate`.

This is my approach:

```
LocalDate month = LocalDate.parse("FEBRUARY 2019", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy"));
```

Or alternatively setting the `Locale.US`:

```
LocalDate month = LocalDate.parse("FEBRUARY 2019", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy", Locale.US));
```

But all I get is the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'FEBRUARY 2019' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: Interesting - I've tried using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseCaseInsensitive()` and that doesn't help either :(

Comment: Even when the case is okay, there's still an error due to the day part being missing, mind you. I'd argue that `YearMonth` is a more suitable type here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest that the input you've got *isn't* a date - it's a year and month. So parse to a `YearMonth`, and then create a `LocalDate` from that however you want. I find it simplest to make text handling code *only* deal with text handling, and perform any other conversions separately when you're in the date/time domain already.

To handle the case sensitivity issue, you can create a `DateTimeFormatter` with case-insensitive parsing. Here's a complete example of that:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Note: this would probably be a field somewhere so you don't need
        // to build it every time.
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("MMMM yyyy")
            .toFormatter(Locale.US);

        YearMonth month = YearMonth.parse("FEBRUARY 2019", formatter);
        System.out.println(month);
    }
}
```

As an alternative approach which could be of use if you have a different representation, you could build a map and pass that to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText`. (I only found this when somehow bungling the code about.)

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO: Build this map up programmatically instead?            
        Map<Long, String> monthNames = new HashMap<>();
        monthNames.put(1L, "JANUARY");
        monthNames.put(2L, "FEBRUARY");
        monthNames.put(3L, "MARCH");
        monthNames.put(4L, "APRIL");
        monthNames.put(5L, "MAY");
        monthNames.put(6L, "JUNE");
        monthNames.put(7L, "JULY");
        monthNames.put(8L, "AUGUST");
        monthNames.put(9L, "SEPTEMBER");
        monthNames.put(10L, "OCTOBER");
        monthNames.put(11L, "NOVEMBER");
        monthNames.put(12L, "DECEMBER");

        // Note: this would probably be a field somewhere so you don't need
        // to build it every time.
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, monthNames)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendPattern("yyyy")
            .toFormatter(Locale.US);

        YearMonth month = YearMonth.parse("FEBRUARY 2019", formatter);
        System.out.println(month);
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, `parseCaseInsensitive` seems to work for me https://ideone.com/6GSCog Unless I missed something.

Comment: @TiiJ7: That's weird - it works for me too now. Will edit the code to show that now. I'd love to know what I did before...

Comment: @TiiJ7: Edited the simpler version in too.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet stated, you don't have a complete date to parse and can use YearMonth. An alternative is to specify a default day.

Instead of the approach to provide a map of months names, you could also simply use a library such as WordUtils to convert your input into the correct format, e.g. as such:

```
final LocalDate month = LocalDate.parse(
        org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils.capitalizeFully("FEBRUARY 2019"),
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("MMMM uuuu")
                    .parseCaseInsensitive()
                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                    .toFormatter(Locale.US));
```

Comment: Giving a default day of month works too and may be a good solution for some. You need to put the call to `parseCaseInsensitive` *before* appending the pattern for it to have effect (so the code doesn’t work as it stands).